# vector subscript out of range error using three vectors, how do I know which one is iterating wrong

Tags: c++, loops, vector, openframeworks

Hi I'm trying to implement the [Diffusion Limited Aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion-limited_aggregation) algorithm in c++ inside openframeworks. I have a class where I define a two vectors, called walkers and fixed, respectively containing the dead and living/moving and not moving particles. My update function goes like this :

```
void DLA::update() {

// Permutation buffer
vector<int> buffer;

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != walkers.size(); ++i) // go through every main/alive particles
{
    walkers[i].update();

    for (std::size_t j = 0; j != fixed.size(); ++j) // go through every fixed/dead particles
    {
        float distance = walkers[i].position.distance(fixed[j].position); // calculate the distance between them
        if (distance < 5) // if the distance is small enough
        {
            buffer.push_back(i); // put the index of the alvie walker in buffer for deletion
        }
    }
}
// Apply buffered information
for (std::size_t i = buffer.size(); i != 0; --i)
{
    walkers[buffer[i]].randomWalk = 0; // make it dead
    fixed.push_back(walkers[buffer[i]]); // put it in the fixed/dead vector
    walkers.erase(walkers.begin() + buffer[i]); // take it out from the main alive vector
}
buffer.clear();
```

}

But each time I run this I get a vector subscript out of range error. Being not familiar with c++ and visual studio, and also not use to relying on frameworks I'm having a hard time reading where the errors come from, because I can't find where in the script that I'm writting the problem is originating from. The compiler sends me to another page of code that belongs to the base openframeworks class codes saying that the errors detected in there.

I have started to go into the debug mode, but from there what I see is the raw values of my RandomWalker array.[image]

What is wrong with my code and how can I diagnoze this clearly from the information that I am given by Visual Studio ? Thx !

edit :

fixed it without using a buffer and just running through both vectors in reverse order

```
for (std::size_t i = walkers.size() - 1; i != -1; --i)
{
    for (std::size_t j = fixed.size() - 1; j != -1; --j) // go through every fixed/dead particles
    {
        // Calculate Distance
        float distance = walkers[i].position.distance(fixed[j].position); 

        if (distance < (walkers[i].radius + fixed[j].radius)) // if the distance is small enough
        {
            walkers[i].randomWalk = 0; // make it dead
            fixed.push_back(walkers[i]); // put it in the fixed/dead vector
            walkers.erase(walkers.begin() + i); // take it out from the main alive vector
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the Call Stack is?

Comment: Aside: `for (auto & walker : walkers)` and `for (auto & fix : fixed)`

Comment: Look at your last `for` loop.  The loop variable `i` is being increased, while the number of entries in `walker` decreases.  See anything wrong that can happen there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this loop

```
// Apply buffered information
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != buffer.size(); ++i)
{
    walkers[i].randomWalk = 0; // make it dead
    fixed.push_back(walkers[i]); // put it in the fixed/dead vector
    walkers.erase(walkers.begin() + i); // take it out from the main alive vector
}
```

You are removing elements from the front of `walkers` as you loop over it, and are limiting it by `buffer.size()`

Are you meaning to use the indexes in `buffer`?

Comment: you're absolutely right, I got confused, I replaced all instance of i by buffer[i] in my last for loop, but I'm getting the same error.
this time I shouldnt be looping over a vector that I'm modifying though

Comment: @Asymetr If you want to remove the first and sixth elements, it matters which order you do it in. If you remove index `0` before index `5`, the element that was at `5` is now at `4`.

Comment: I'm trying to iterate backwards through the buffer to fix this issue using (std::size_t i = buffer.size(); i != 0; --i) in the for loop but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You could use `std::set<std::size_t, std::greater<>> buffer;` instead, so that it's unique and in descending order